# How can I make this prime check function more succinct in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, math, primes

So I spent the last hour or so trying to write up an effecient haskell function that checks if a number is prime or not. I came up with this algorithm that I'm rather happy with:

```
prime :: Int -> Bool
prime x
    | x == 1 = False
    | x == 2 = True
    | x == 3 = True
    | x `mod` 2 == 0 = False
    | x `mod` 3 == 0 = False
    | otherwise = all (\y -> x `mod` y /= 0) $ dividends x
    where
        dividends z =
            takeWhile ((<=) . floor . sqrt . fromIntegral $ z)
                $ concatMap (\x -> [x-1, x+1]) [6 * x | x <- [1..]]
```

I also uploaded a notebook that checks the run time of the algorithm and compares it to the sieve method in case anyone is interested that is here: https://anaconda.org/freemo/primes/notebook

My question is, as someone new to haskell how can I make this algorithm more idomatic. I have a feeling the anonymous functions I used can be eliminated, and there are probably other ways I can make it more concise without having a negative effect on the run time. How can I write this in an more idiomatic haskell way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The thing I'd consider most unidiomatic here are the equality comparisons. In Haskell, we generally prefer pattern matching, which you can directly apply to the first three cases:

```
prime 1 = False
prime 2 = True
prime 3 = True
prime x
    | ...
```

(The difference is cosmetic in this example, but often pattern matching makes code much safer, more succinct and sometimes also significantly more performant.)

Next, you're using both a list comprehension and `concatMap`. Both constructs do largely the same thing, and are equivalent to monadic binds. But **a)** it's usually benefitial to use only *one* of these syntaxes in a place, **b)** monad is actually stronger than necessary: *applicative* will do as well, and can be written quite nicely here.

```
import Control.Applicative
...
       (6*) <$> [1..] <**> [pred, succ]
```

Then, I find this `((<=) . floor . sqrt . fromIntegral $ z)` awkward. More natural would be in flipped form:

```
    takeWhile (>= floor (sqrt $ fromIntegral z)) ...
```

...but generally speaking, better yet is to avoid the square root entirely:

```
    takeWhile ((>=z) . (^2)) ...
```

The reason being, square-root is pretty expensive and has floating-point inaccuracies, so it's often better to square the other side of the equation instead. Unfortunately, this is actually not reliable here, because the squaring might lead to `Int` overflows, and `Integer` would make the performance probably *worse* than with float-sqrt, because it's done for every element of the list rather than just once. So, a square-root is actually sensible here.

The `dividends` function is actually superfluous since you only ever call it with `x` as the argument. (It might be argued that it's sensible to still give this a *name*, but at any rate you don't need to give it an *argument*.)

The predicate for the `all` is something I *would* consider making point-free.

Final version would then be:

```
prime :: Int -> Bool
prime 1 = False
prime 2 = True
prime 3 = True
prime x
    | x `mod` 2 == 0 = False
    | x `mod` 3 == 0 = False
    | otherwise = all ((/= 0) . (x`mod`))
                 . takeWhile (>= floor (sqrt $ fromIntegral x))
                 $ (6*) <$> [1..]
                        <**> [pred, succ]
```

Comment: This feels like the right answer. Some ideas are new to me so I need to play with it to confirm. So unless i find an issue or a better answer comes along I will probably accept this as the answer shortly.

Comment: so Applicatives, <**> and <$> are all weird to me and i dont understand what they are. If I learn about applicatives will that also cover whatever those other two things are?

Comment: @JeffreyPhillipsFreeman: `<$>` is infix `fmap :: (a -> b) -> f a -> f b`, a.k.a. `map` on lists (`f`=`[]`). So `(6*) <$> [1..]` = `[6,12,18,…]`. `<**>` is a flipped version of `(<*>) :: f (a -> b) -> f a -> f b`—here, applying a list of functions to a list of operands. This answer uses `<**>` instead of the (more common) `<*>` because they give different orderings: `[pred,succ] <*> [10,20,30] == [9,19,29,11,21,31]` (all `pred`s then all `succ`s) while `[10,20,30] <**> [pred,succ] == [9,11,19,21,29,31]` (`pred` and `succ` of each). Just a shorter version of `… >>= \x -> [pred x, succ x]`.

Answer (score 1):

So I modified @leftaroundabout 's answer slightly and am using this. Just putting it up here in case anyone winds up using it.

```
import Control.Applicative

prime'' :: Int -> Bool
prime'' 1 = False
prime'' 2 = True
prime'' 3 = True
prime'' x
    | x `mod` 2 == 0 = False
    | x `mod` 3 == 0 = False
    | otherwise = all
                     -- check if x is not divisibile by the divisors
                     ((/=  0) . (x `mod`))

                     -- only take divisors less than or equal to sqrt(x)
                     . takeWhile (<=(floor . sqrt . fromIntegral $ x))

                     -- generate divisors as an infinite list 6n +/- 1
                     $ [6,12..] <**> [(-1+), (1+)]
```